# FetchedResultsController Using Predicate to Exclude Results Contained in a Set

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

I am attempting to filter the items in my FetchedResultsController to filter out a certain set of items. These are engines which have a certain letter designation in them followed by numbers. The possible rage of letters in the designation are from "A" to "O". I would like to be able to filter out engines that have the designations from "D" to "O" based on another condition.

I set a constant "highPowerEngines" that is a set containing those letters. Since the designation only contains one letter, I want to exclude any designation that contains any of the letters in highPowerEngines. So far, this is my code, the predicate I am working on is contained after the FIXME:

```
func configureFetchedResultsController() {
    let context = databaseController.getContext()
    let enginesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Engine>(entityName: CoreData.engine)
    let highPowerEngines: Set =  ["D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]

    var predicate = NSPredicate()
    if currentStage == 1 && stages! == 1 {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "engineType == %@", EngineType.singleStage.rawValue)
    } else if currentStage < stages! {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "engineType == %@", EngineType.boosterStage.rawValue)
    } else {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "engineType == %@", EngineType.upperStage.rawValue)
    }

    var predicateArray:[NSPredicate] = [
        predicate
        ]
    // FIXME: Sort out highPowerEngines
    if !dPlusEngineIAP {
        if currentStage == 1 && stages! == 1 {
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT engineDesignation CONTAINS %@", highPowerEngines)
            predicateArray.append(predicate)
        }
    }

    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArray)
    enginesFetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate

    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: CoreData.isMadeByName, ascending: true)
    let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: CoreData.engineDesignation, ascending: true)
    enginesFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor, secondarySortDescriptor]


    self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Engine>(
        fetchRequest: enginesFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: CoreData.isMadeByName,
        cacheName: nil)

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the post here: [CoreData Predicate get every sentence that contains any word in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085345/coredata-predicate-get-every-sentence-that-contains-any-word-in-array)
, I was finally able to solve my problem. My current working code is here:

```
func configureFetchedResultsController() {
    let context = databaseController.getContext()
    let enginesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Engine>(entityName: CoreData.engine)
    let lowPowerEngines =  ["A", "B", "C"]

    var predicate = NSPredicate()
    if currentStage == 1 && stages! == 1 {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "engineType == %@", EngineType.singleStage.rawValue)
    } else if currentStage < stages! {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "engineType == %@", EngineType.boosterStage.rawValue)
    } else {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "engineType == %@", EngineType.upperStage.rawValue)
    }

    var predicateArray:[NSPredicate] = [
        predicate
        ]

    if !dPlusEngineIAP {
        let predicates = lowPowerEngines.map {
            NSPredicate(format: "engineDesignation CONTAINS %@", $0)
        }
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
            predicateArray.append(predicate)
    }

    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArray)
    enginesFetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate

    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: CoreData.isMadeByName, ascending: true)
    let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: CoreData.engineDesignation, ascending: true)
    enginesFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor, secondarySortDescriptor]


    self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Engine>(
        fetchRequest: enginesFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: CoreData.isMadeByName,
        cacheName: nil)

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

}
```

The solution to dealing with each item in the array was to make a compound predicate using the map function. Then adding the compound predicate to the fetchedResultsController. That allows me to compare the engine to see if it is in lowPowerEngines. Map makes a separate predicate for each item in lowPowerEngines. I could even change it programmatically on the fly. I really hope this helps someone as there is no central place to come up with these sort of tricks. When I collect enough of them, I will do a master post.

Answer (score 0):

Use IN instead of CONTAINS

```
NOT (engineDesignation IN %@)
```

**update**

Since you want to exclude all but tree letters why not turn the predicate around to include rather than exclude, something like

```
engineDesignation BEGINSWITH ‘A’ OR
engineDesignation BEGINSWITH ‘B’ OR
engineDesignation BEGINSWITH ‘C’
```

Comment: It isn't excluding the high power engines. I put a breakpoint in and it is definitely executing the code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, engineDesignation is a string that is a letter followed by other non-letter characters, if that changes things.

Comment: If it begins with a letter you should be using BEGINSWITH but I’m pretty sure that won’t work with a Set and I don’t really see any solution then that would work with a collection of letters apart from creating a massive compound OR predicate and checking each letter separately.

Comment: @Yrb I updated my answer with an alternative solution

Comment: No joy. it can't parse it with the "or"s. And you are right, BEGINSWITH doesn't work with a set or an array. Can I tell you I really hate string literals in predicates?!?

Comment: Too bad, a completely different solution could be to add a boolean attribute and it depending on what the value of engineDestination starts with. A workaround for sure but maybe something worth considering.

Comment: I was able to come up with the solution.