# How to filter out Core Data Objects using an NSSet Attribute and an arbitrary Set?

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, array-filter

I have a core data class that looks like this:

```
@objc(ManagedObject)
fileprivate class MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var features: Set<String>
    @NSManaged public var someId:String
}
```

And I would like to search object using a predicate on the `features` attribute, where the intersection between `features` and `user_features` passed by a user isn't null. In other words:

```
func find(features:Set<String>) -> [ManagedObject]? {
       do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest< ManagedObject >(entityName: "the name")
        request.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "...", features)
        let fetchResults:[ManagedObject] = try self.managedContext.fetch(request)
        return fetchResults
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
    return nil

}
```

I tried `request.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "features IN %@", features)`, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

What's the proper predicate to filter a Set attribute, based on its intersection against another Set? Is this possible with Core Data?

Comment: Try `ANY features IN %@`.

Comment: Is `features` declared as transformable?  That might be the problem: transformables are stored in SQLite as binary data, so you can't use predicates on them (at least not as part of a fetch).

Comment: @Willeke unfortunately same results, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @pbasdf yes, it's a transformable, so it makes sense I can't find anything. That sucks.... :( thanks!

Comment: Just thinking out loud, off the top of your heads, is there an algorithm that does what I want in a reasonable time?

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085345/coredata-predicate-get-every-sentence-that-contains-any-word-in-array), we change

```
@objc(ManagedObject)
fileprivate class MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var features: Set<String>
    @NSManaged public var someId:String
}
```

to

```
@objc(ManagedObject)
fileprivate class MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var features: String
    @NSManaged public var someId:String
}
```

where `features` is obtained from the original set `features = features.map({$0}).joined("_")`

Then we can use the query, using words:Set as the searched set

```
let regex = ".*(" + words.map {
    NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: $0)
}.joined(separator: "|") + ").*"

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "features MATCHES %@", regex)
```

Big thanks to the original author, [@MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)